# Subversion authorization

Tags: svn, authorization

I have installed Apache Subversion on my linux server under */var/svn*

Currently we are doing two projects in our company with 2 groups:

- The first group is using the Subversion under:

`https://www.lumiin.ch/svn/lumin/trunk`

- The second group is using the Subversion under:

`https://www.lumiin.ch/svn/lumin/trunk/mindmade/html5`

Now the problem is the second group is able to **read / write** the code from the first group link.

Now i want to restrict the second group user from the first group link. They **should not able to read / write** the code.

How to deny authorization for second group users for the path?

Can any help me out in this?

Regards
Karthick

Comment: BTW it's called 'authorization' (it's about access rights) not 'authentication' (this one is about user's identity check). 

See the difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication

Answer (score 4):

I assume you serve your SVN via apache2 using the `SVNPath` directive.

First add there authentication requirement to `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /mnt/big/svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Server"
  # create svn.pass using htpasswd
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn.pass
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Then add in the `Location` section `AuthzSVNAccessFile` directive pointing to file that will define permissions, e.g.:

```
[groups]
group1=martin,jane,bob
group2=jane,james,johan

[/]
* = r

[/project1]
* =
@group1 = rw

[/project1]
* =
@group2 = rw
```

You can find much more info eg in the [version control with subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) - especially [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir).

Answer (score 1):

I see the other issue, **the fundamental one**, if I can call it so. It's not about authorization (**pQd**'s answer pretty much covers the authorization topic).

*Why did you organize your repository this way?*

You have 2 groups working on different projects but the projects are placed under main branch 'trunk'.

*Why don't you use separate branches for separate groups of users or for separate projects?*

For me it looks like your repository is poorly organized (as far as I see and understand).
You should definitely consider the SVNBook article: ["Strategies for Repository Deployment"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.planning.html).